# VMWare java SDK: When doesn't an available PerfMetricID report Data?

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere, vmware-sdk

I'm trying to use vmware sdk for java to collect the perfomance data of each entity (cluster/datastore/Host/VM) in the vmware environment.
The idea is to get the available PerfMetricIds for the target entity with `queryAvailablePerfMetric`, query those and report the details of the counter, the timestamp and the value.

However when I get the PerfMetricIds for an entity, not every detected (returned) PerfMetricId is reporting data. For example for each Datastore I get at least 4 ids which do not return data when queried, these IDs represent the counters associated with the average number of read and write operations, and for a cluster I'm missing the cpu usage, and so on ...

so I was wondering when does this happen? Shouldn't every metric returned by `queryAvailablePerfMetric` report data? what am I missing here?

Minimal code snippet:

```java
// VMWare credentials
String vmwareUrl = args[0];
String vmwareUsername = args[1];
String vmwarePassword = args[2];

// connect to vCenter
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(vmwareUrl), vmwareUsername, vmwarePassword, true);
// get performance manager
PerformanceManager perfMgr = si.getPerformanceManager();

// define the time window (the last one hour)
Calendar calTo = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
calFrom.setTime(calTo.getTime());
calFrom.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);

// get any datastore for testing purposes
Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();
ManagedEntity[] datastores = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("Datastore");
ManagedEntity me = datastores[1];

// query all available metrics for the entity
PerfMetricId[] availablePmis = perfMgr.queryAvailablePerfMetric(me, calFrom, calTo, perfMgr.getHistoricalInterval()[0].getSamplingPeriod());

// create PerfQuerySpec
PerfQuerySpec qSpec = new PerfQuerySpec();
qSpec.setEntity(me.getMOR());
qSpec.setMetricId(availablePmis);
qSpec.setFormat("csv");
qSpec.setStartTime(calFrom);
qSpec.setEndTime(calTo);

// query perf
PerfEntityMetricBase[] perfValues = perfMgr.queryPerf(new PerfQuerySpec[]{qSpec});

// Printing
System.out.println("Found pmis (CounterIDs only): ");
for (PerfMetricId pmi : availablePmis){
    System.out.print(pmi.getCounterId() + ", ");
}
System.out.print("\nPmis with values:");
int pmisCount=0;
for (PerfEntityMetricBase value : perfValues) {
    PerfMetricSeriesCSV[] csvValues = ((PerfEntityMetricCSV) value).getValue();
    pmisCount += csvValues.length;;
    for (PerfMetricSeriesCSV csv : csvValues) {
        System.out.println("Counter ID: " + csv.getId().getCounterId() + " ---- Metric instance: " + csv.getId().getInstance());
        System.out.println("\tInfo: " + ((PerfEntityMetricCSV) value).getSampleInfoCSV());
        System.out.println("\tValues: " + csv.getValue());
    }
}
System.out.println("---------------");
System.out.println("Detected PMIs: " + availablePmis.length);
System.out.println("PMIs with values: " + pmisCount);
```

Any help (or discussions) would be appreciated